# user comment display on asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page which uses the asp membership control. I want to use the user comment field to hold an additional piece of information. I'm creating the user via the Web Site Administration Tool.

So how would I access the comment field and write it to the page?

Ok I'm not totally mad (well maybe but that's my state of mind!).
the comment field lives in the aspnet_Membership table if you create a user and go to manage that user you see it has a Description labelled text box this maps through to the Comment field.

Maybe I'm using the wrong terms! sorry...

[image: Description text box that maps to the comment field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what "comment field" you are talking about, because the default Web Site Administration Tool created users don't have such fields.

If you want to create such a field you would need to implement different `MembershipProvider` class or work with [Profile properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

I would recommend you to read these articles first:

- [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx)
- [Storing Additional User Information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

**EDIT:**

For that particular "Description" field (wich I'm sure wasn't there when I was looking for it >.<), it really puts data into "aspnet_Membership" table "Comment" column.
You can easily access it with [`MembershipUser` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx):

```
@{MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();}
@if ( user != null)
{
    @user.Comment
}
```

Razor syntax

**EDIT**

[`Membership.GetUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx) support simple overrides so you don't really need to use `Context.User.Identity.Name` as parameter for currently logged-on user.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta go with Ilya on this one... I'm not seeing a "comment" field in my instance of Web Site Adminstration.

But, a possible answer to your question would be ASP.NET Profiles:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx

Comment: Thank you both, I will look at this on wednesday when I'm back but I have updated the question with information relating to the "comment field".